# Proof that small change in temperature leads to small change in entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, differentiation, calculus

I have been trying to find a mathematical proof (or even from a reliable source) which verifies that/proves that:

A small change in temperature leads to a small change in entropy.

However, I was unable to find one with a relation between change in entropy and change in temperature. Can someone please help me?

Edit: this "small" is related to: [image]

Comment: Quantify “small.” It is impossible to answer this question without more detail about what you are looking for, where you found the original claim, etc.

Comment: Done, I added it in the post! Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @MattHanson Come on, "a small change of something corresponds to a small change of something else" is just a way to say that "something else" is a continuous function of "something".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to prove the statement in general, because it's not generally true.

If I vent air into a vacuum, for example, the initial and final temperatures of the air are identical—but its entropy has increased.

If I perform a phase change at a constant temperature, the temperature change is zero—but the entropy of the material can change substantially (e.g., from a liquid to a gas).

If all I'm doing is heating a single phase, though (termed [sensible heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_heat)), and nothing else notable is occurring, then a slight increase in temperature does correspond to a slight increase in entropy.

Here's how we prove that.

Assuming a closed system of a single phase, we can add energy to it only by heating it or doing work on it. We can therefore differentially expand the entropy $S$ as a function of two variables—say, temperature $T$ and something else (pressure $P$ or volume $V$). We might assume that the pressure remains constant, so let's pick pressure:

$$ dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{dP};$$

$$dS=\frac{C_P}{T}\,dT,$$

where $C_P\equiv T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P$ is the heat capacity of the system at constant pressure. (Note that we recover the expected result that the heat capacity is infinite during heating to produce a first-order phase transition.) This connects an infinitesimal change in temperature to an infinitesimal change in entropy, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Entropy is defined as:
$$ 
\Delta S = \int_A^B \left (\frac{\delta Q}{T} \right) _{rev}
$$
Where $A$ and and $B$ are state of the system, $\delta Q$ is the differential of exchanged heath and $T$ the temperature. The little "rev" meand that the path that this system follows to get from $A$ to $B$ is reversible.

If we keep unchanged the exchanged heath and the states $A$ and $B$ you notice that the whole integral depends linearly on $T$.

Note that $T$ **is a function of the state** and in general it is not constant when exchanging heath.
This means that we should compute how chaning a function ($T$) changes another function ($\Delta S$) and to do so we need the mathematical tool called variational calculus.

Anyway, we can deal with it considering the fact that $T$ is continuous and the dependance of $\Delta S$ is linear so, overall the latter is continuous with respect of the first one.
Continuity means exactly that a "small" change on the first, produces a "small" change in the one that depends on it.

I'm not sure if this answer is exactly spot on about what you asked but I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a change in entropy without a change in temperature (e.g. a reversible isothermal expansion or compression of a gas) and you can have a change in temperature without a change in entropy (e.g., a reversible adiabatic expansion or compression of a gas).

Start with the basic definition of a differential entropy change:

$$dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$

Where $\delta Q _{rev}$ refers to a reversible transfer of heat between the system and its surroundings, and $T$ is the temperature at the boundary between the system and its surroundings. Then the finite change in entropy between any equilibrium states 1 and 2 is

$$\Delta S_{12}=\int_1^2\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$

If the temperature of the surroundings is kept infinitesimally close to the temperature of the system, the process becomes isothermal (constant temperature). $T$ comes out of the integral and we have

$$\Delta S_{12}=\frac{Q_{rev}}{T}$$

Giving us a change in entropy without a change in temperature.

Next consider a reversible adiabatic adiabatic expansion or compression of an ideal gas. Since $Q=0$ and the process is reversible so that no entropy is generated within the gas, the process is constant entropy, i.e., $\Delta S=0$. However, from the first law

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$ and thus

$$\Delta U=-W$$

For an ideal gas, any process, $\Delta U=C_{v}\Delta T$. Thus compression or expansion work will increase or decrease, respectively, the internal energy and therefore an increase or decrease in temperature of the gas.

So here we have a change in temperature without a change in entropy.

Hope this helps.